# Single use timestamp in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date, timestamp, worksheet

I'm trying to create an Excel logbook and want a timestamp that captures when the information in another field was inserted or changed the first time.  I'm able to use VBA and create a timestamp but if the user goes back and changes the data in the target cell, the timestamp updates as well.

For my test purposes, I insert basic information in Column B and Column A in the same row generates a timestamp which is correct.  If I go back and change the information in that row in Column B, the timestamp updates which is what I don't want.

How can I keep the timestamp from updating once inserted?

Current timestamp VBA code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim xRInt As Integer

Dim xDStr As String

Dim xFStr As String

On Error Resume Next

xDStr = "B" 'Data Column

xFStr = "A" 'Timstamp Column

If (Not Application.Intersect(Me.Range(xDStr & ":" & xDStr), Target) Is Nothing) Then

       xRInt = Target.Row

       Me.Range(xFStr & xRInt) = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: First, remove `On Error Resume Next`. Then, use `Long` instead of `Integer`. Then,  to solve your main problem, use `IsEmpty` to check if the cell in `A` is empty or not before writing the timestamp.

Comment: @BigBen This worked perfectly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change - Time Stamp

- When values in cells of column `B` are changed manually or via `VBA`, if not already, the code will add a time stamp to the cells in the same rows of column `A`.

**The Code**

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    TimeStampSimple Target, "B2", "A", "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", False
End Sub

Sub TimeStampSimple( _
        ByVal Target As Range, _
        ByVal SourceFirstCellAddress As String, _
        ByVal TimeColumnString As String, _
        Optional ByVal TimeFormat As String = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", _
        Optional ByVal OverwriteTimeStamps As Boolean = False)

    ' The Source range is the single-column range from the first Source cell
    ' to the bottom-most cell of the worksheet.
    ' When a change happens in any cell of the Source range:
    ' If OverwriteTimeStamps is set to True, it will write the time stamp.
    ' If OverwriteTimeStamps is set to False, it will write the time stamp
    ' only once i.e. if the cell in the same row of the Time column is blank.
    
    Dim sfCell As Range
    Dim rgSource As Range
    Dim rgChange As Range
    Dim ChangeTimeColumnOffset As Long
    
    With Target.Worksheet
        Set sfCell = .Range(SourceFirstCellAddress)
        Set rgSource = sfCell.Resize(.Rows.Count - sfCell.Row + 1)
        Set rgChange = Intersect(rgSource, Target)
        If rgChange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no changed cells in Source range
        ChangeTimeColumnOffset _
            = .Columns(TimeColumnString).Column - sfCell.Column
    End With
    
    Dim rgTime As Range: Set rgTime = rgChange.Offset(, ChangeTimeColumnOffset)
    
    Dim rgTimeCells As Range
    
    If OverwriteTimeStamps Then
        Set rgTimeCells = rgTime
    Else
        Dim tCell As Range
        
        For Each tCell In rgTime.Cells
            If Len(CStr(tCell.Value)) = 0 Then ' the Time cell is blank; combine
                If rgTimeCells Is Nothing Then
                    Set rgTimeCells = tCell
                Else
                    Set rgTimeCells = Union(rgTimeCells, tCell)
                End If
            'Else ' the Time cell is not blank; do nothing
            End If
        Next tCell
        
        If rgTimeCells Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no blank cells
    End If
    
    Dim TimeStamp As String: TimeStamp = Format(Now, TimeFormat)
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False ' to not retrigger the event
        rgTimeCells.Value = TimeStamp
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```